# MDI windows menu items in Window menu

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, mdi

In MFC application system automatically appends opened documents as menu items at the end of the **Window** menu (second from the right). If count of window menu items exceeds 9, system appends the **More Windows...** item.

1. How to change maximum window count (9)?
2. Where is the code responsible for appending these menu items (MFC, system dll)?
3. How to localize text of the menu item **More Windows...**?

Comment: See [Custom MDI “More Windows” Dialog](http://codexpert.ro/blog/2012/12/30/custom-mdi-more-windows-dialog/). Although not a direct answer to your questions, it is a good start point.

Comment: The same person has put more info about it on http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?531501-RESOLVED-MDI-quot-More-Windows-quot-dialog&p=2097709#post2097709